# $y=\sin (x + \frac{\pi}{3})\cos x \ ,0 \leq x \leq \pi $,I have to put $y' = 0$ and obtain equation $\cos(2x +\frac{\pi}{3})=0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry

$$y=\sin (x + \frac{\pi}{3})\cos x \ ,0 \leq x \leq \pi $$

I have to put $y' = 0$ and obtain equation $\cos(2x +\frac{\pi}{3})=0$

I get stuck at $y' ={\cos^2 (x)} -\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{3})\sin x$

How do I proceed further ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply the product rule to differentiate $y$:
$$y'=\cos\Bigl(x+\frac\pi3\Bigr)\cos x-\sin\Bigl(x+\frac\pi3\Bigr)\sin x=\cos\Bigl(x+\frac\pi3+x\Bigr)$$
by the addition formula.